# Hibernate 4.2.2 The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, hibernate

I've been working through several Hibernate Tutorial but the application won't run. I get a JDBCConnectionException.

I think maybe there is something wrong with the connection settings: "ERROR: I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

Therefore I linked the SQL Developer Settings and my hibernate.cfg.xml.

[Link to SQL Developer Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NISmM.jpg)

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="connection.password">test</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <mapping resource="TEST.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the Main Class:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
    private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Session session = getSession();


        final Test a1 = new Ankuendigung(3,"AA", "AAAA");
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(a1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        try {
            System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
            final Map metadataMap = session.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
            for (Object key : metadataMap.keySet()) {
                final ClassMetadata classMetadata = (ClassMetadata) metadataMap.get(key);
                final String entityName = classMetadata.getEntityName();
                final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
                System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
                for (Object o : query.list()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + o);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
   Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Ankuendigung.hbm.xml
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:22 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=vias, password=****}
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:25 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:25 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
Apr 19, 2016 11:31:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
    at Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
    ... 22 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, add a full stack trace and your configuration code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Url is not valid

```
<property name="connection.url">000.000.000.000:11111</property>
```

try this out :

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
```

orcl is the default instance name, You can find the SID/SERVICE name in your tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: I tried this out and used "xe" as SID, because it is also used in the SQL Developer Settings. Now there are new Errors. I edited my Post with the new Stack Trace.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is solved!!!

The URL was wrong (Thanks to Mohamed) and I had to add the configuration details from the Sql Developer settings (Host, Port & SID).

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@000.000.000.000:1111:xe</property>
```